# How best to express a set of mutually inequivalent objects?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I would like to express that I have a pair of inequivalent objects. Going further, I would like to be able to express that they are wholly defined by this inequivalence, i.e that this is all that is *knowable* about them. More generally I would like to be able to express this for any number of mutually inequivalent objects.

It may seem paradoxical to say that two objects are not equivalent when all that is knowable about each one amounts to the same thing (i.e. that they are mutually inequivalent with other such objects). If it helps, I am not so much interested in making assertions about the individual objects themselves, so much as the whole system (i.e. its symmery being a feature of interest).

The best analogy that I can come up with is that of a set of random variables which are jointly distributed such that their realized values are never equal, but that is not what I want to convey.

All that I can come up with is simply:
$$\{X, Y\} \vert X \not \equiv Y $$
or, for the general case, something like:
$$\{X_1, X_2, \ldots ,X_n\} \vert (\forall i, j \in [1 ..n] \vert i \not = j ) X_i \not \equiv X_j$$
...but this seems far too easy, and too ambiguous.

Comment: This seems fine to me.  Also fine is *using words instead of symbols*.  There is no rule that you must use symbols to convey something.  If conveying what you want with words is simple and concise enough, just keep it as words.